# Extract a column value based on conditions applied to other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe:

[image]

Here I am trying to fetch the 'start_planting_date' based on unique 'crop' value having the maximum 'count'.

pandas loc[] query:

[image]

**Example**: I want to know the **start_planting_date** for the **crop == Maize** having the maximum **count** value, i.e., 1087 in this case.

Can there be a better/more optimized way of writing this query?

Comment: Put the actual dataframe code instead of the image!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want only the max value for each group, try using:

```
df.groupby('crop').max()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `crop` and get the index of maximum `count` for each `crop` with [`GroupBy.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to locate the entries of those max indexes, as follows:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('crop')['count'].idxmax()]
```